# Tool that can add HTTP Headers

Tags: proxy, http-headers, webserver, reverse-proxy

I need a tool that I can set up between my client browser a web server that will allow me to add HTTP headers into the response coming back from the web server. I am envisioning that the tool would run, like fiddler, my client browser goes through fillder to connect to the webserver and I can configure fiddler to modify the HTTP respones coming back i.e. to add in an HTTP header. Are there tools that can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this in production or for development only?

For production, use Apache and its many modules.

Would the tool be on yor PC (forward proxy) or server (reverse proxy)? Apache can be used for both.

If development only, fiddler does the job?

Comment: We will use something Fiddler-like (WebScarab) since we're not allowed to install fiddler.